# CPU usage extremely high on TS deployment

Tags: c#, .net, cpu, memory-management

Our application is written in .NET (framework 3.5). We are experiencing problems with the applications performance when deployed in a terminal services environment. The client is using a TS farm. They have 4GB ram and a decent xeon processor.

When the application is opened in this environment, it sits at 25% CPU usage even when idle. When deployed in a normal client - server environment, it behaves normally, spiking the CPU usage when necessary and drops down to 0 when idle.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? Or, what I could do to investigate? We have no memory leaks that we can find using performance profiling tools.

1. This is a WinForms application
2. We dont have a TS environment avialable to test on
3. The application is a Business Application.

Basically, capturing and updating of data. Its a massive business application, but there is little multithreading, listeners etc. We do have ANTS profiler (memory / performance) but as mentioned in our environment we dont have the problem - it only occurs on the TS environment

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few questions before we can really get you too far.

1. Is this a Console Application?  WinForms Application? or Windows Service?
2. Do you have a Terminal Services environment available?
3. What does your application do?

Depending on what the application does, you might check to see if there is unusually high activity on their hardware that you have not accounted for.  Examples that I have noticed in the past are items such as having a FileSystemWatcher accidentally listening to a "drop location" for reporting on a client server.  Things of that nature, items that while "idle" shouldn't be busy, but are.

Otherwise, if you have the ability to do so, you could also use a tool such as ANTS Profiler from RedGate to see WHAT is using the CPU time on the environment.

Comment: 1. This is a WinForms application
2. We dont have a TS environment avialable to test on
3. The application is a Business Application. Basically, capturing and updating of data. Its a massive business application, but there is little multithreading, listeners etc.

We do have ANTS profiler (memory / performance) but as mentioned in our environment we dont have the problem - it only occurs on the TS environment

Answer (score 0):

Look for sections in your application that constantly repaints the window.   Factor those out so that when sitting idle it isn't constantly repainting the window.